# Can I link from a Google Sheet to a Google Doc heading?

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

Can I link from a Google Sheet, to a specific heading in Google Docs?

I can link to a Google Docs, so it opens it and shows the beginning, but I would like to jump immediately to a specific heading within that Google Document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Google Docs text file that you want to link to, click the target heading. The browser address bar will contain an URL that looks like this:

`https://docs.google.com/document/d/bl51...gI5D/edit#heading=h.58vpqpdxtmnt`

Copy and paste the URL to the spreadsheet. To make the link nicer looking, use **Insert > Link** or the `hyperlink()` function. When you click the link in the spreadsheet, it will open the text file at the heading you selected.

Comment: Thanks, I would expected a 'nicer looking'  link, but it works.

Comment: You can make the link nicer looking through **Insert > Link** or by using the `hyperlink()` function.

Comment: Thanks for the nice addition.